# How can I force the user to log in, even if they're already authenticated?

Tags: redirect, login, authentication

I am creating a link to a Wordpress page. In this scenario, multiple users may use the same machine and get confused about who is logged in, so every time they follow the link they must be forced to log in again.

(This is a convenience/UX issue, not a security issue, so the fact that they could easily bypass the login is not a concern.)

So the link should:

1. Force them to log in again
2. Then take them to the page

I have tried

```
https://wordpress.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://wordpress.example.com/slug&reauth=1
```

but it seems I can't rely on reauth=1 to force the login.

Is there another way to do this?